# Meaning of "Turn east for half a mile"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

Here is a note from a video game:

> Go through the fields.
>   **Turn east for half a mile**.
>   It's just past the big rock on the right.

I am not sure about the meaning of the second line. The official Russian translation sounds like *Go half a mile and turn east*, but shouldn't it be *Turn east and go half a mile*, with turning east being the first action and going half a mile (eastward) the second one? The preposition *for* seems to me the purpose of the turning, which is to go half a mile.

Comment: Should the question be about the translation of the original Russian usage?

Comment: Edit: the question is not clear. Do you really want to know how to interpret the 2nd line of instructions, or do you want to clarify what the translation from Russian *should* say?

Comment: @CorvusB I wanted to know what the original English sentence really meant, but I appreciated MAKZ's attempt to describe what it would be like if the translation was correct. Chenmunka's answer is also very helpful and interesting, but I can't accept both answers at a time, so I had to decide on only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The sentence closely means *'Turn east in order to go next half a mile of your journey'*, but sounds quite unnatural.

You say "The official Russian translation sounds like Go half a mile and turn east". To match with the Russian instruction, the correct preposition required is *after* so that the sentence would be *'Turn east **after** half a mile.*

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct in that it means "*turn east and then go half a mile*".

It is worth noting that this is almost certainly a dialect expression.  Certainly in British English "*turn ... for ...*" is ambiguous and almost never heard.  As you say, it could just as easily mean "*go half a mile and then turn east*".  We would use the full sentence as above.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an "American English expression"... I'd call it "poorly written directions, no matter what dialect you're speaking".

Comment: @T.J.L.  I've only ever heard it from Americans so maybe I'm maligning a whole nation from just a few examples.

Comment: That was my point, yes. :) It's a big country; there are ways that people in certain parts of the country speak that people in other parts of the country find appalling.

Comment: I've removed the American references.

Comment: It might be an American usage. It does not sound unusual to me, but at the same time, it is *not* clear! Calling it *"poorly written directions"* fits, I think.